# How to fill label with multiple lines?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a label inside grid inside listview that retrieve data from API with multiple lines and I want to display all lines in that label.

```
     <ListView x:Name="visitList" SeparatorColor="Black" 
         SeparatorVisibility="Default" BackgroundColor="White">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Padding="2">
                            <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding CustomerName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding status}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FormattedText property from the Label, it would look something like this:

```
<Label FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoBold}" FontSize="14">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Time: "/>
            <Span Text="{Binding Time}"/>
            <Span Text=" Costumer: "/>
            <Span Text="{Binding CustomerName}"/>
            <Span Text=" Status: "/>
            <Span Text="{Binding status}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

And you can format it the way you want, in the end it will be only one label with all the text concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but you've got a few things to try/adjust here.

1. Firstly, set your ListView property `HasUnevenRows` equal to true.  That's imperative.
2. Secondly, you've specified that you want to have 3 columns of labels but you haven't specified any columns for your grid.
3. Finally, `LineBreakMode` as a property against the labels, by default it's meant to word wrap but just check that if it all still doesn't work.

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="visitList" SeparatorColor="Black" SeparatorVisibility="Default" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="true">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                   <Frame Padding="2">
                       <Grid>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                           <Label Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                           <Label Text="{Binding CustomerName}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                           <Label Text="{Binding status}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                       </Grid>
                   </Frame>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

Like I said, untested but see if it helps.